# How do I change the default icon of iPhone application programmatically?

Tags: iphone, icons

My question is about changing default icon.png content programmatically.

1. I have free application with Icon (with Lite/Free word inside)
2. I have In-App purchase inside this app (buy full version)
3. I click and accept this purchase
4. Some app content is unlocked
5. Also, I want my default Icon.png to be changed as well (replace it with NON Lite/Free word inside for example)

I saw this approach in some games but did not buy them to see the results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot change the application's icon at runtime. This is because it is in the application's bundle, which cannot be modified. Access to the application's bundle is restricted for security. Each bundle is code-signed by a certificate obtained through Apple's developer portal, which guarantees this condition.

To conclude, any files inside the application's bundle, like icons, or the Info.plist file, cannot be changed.

Comment: Can I change name of application icon in runtime? I know that default value is Icon.png, so could I change it after purchase ?

Comment: No, because the name resides in the Info.plist file, which is also in the app's bundle. Apple recommends creating a separate Lite version and a Full version of your application.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure since you have purchased it you don't have source code.. but still try to  look for image icon which must be in application folder.. just delete that icon and put whatever image you want with the same image name.. Also for that one.. you might have to install folder navigation icon. And then you can look in which folder it is install.. I ain't sure but it might be something called /app  or /data. I am most of the time playing with android so I know for android where to look.

Thanks

Comment: iOS is quite different in this case, I don't think that will work