# PNG within an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, png

I have the following issue:

My iPhone app makes some kind of graphics.

How can I save these graphics or drawings made by the app as a png file on the device?

Would it then be possible to set such a png file to become the icon for the app from within the app itself? (Provided the size is right of course.)

Thanks for any possible tip.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't change the app's icon at runtime (like the Calendar app that comes with the iPhone does)

[How do I change the default icon of iPhone application programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7150351/how-do-i-change-the-default-icon-of-iphone-application-programmatically)

Answer (score 1):

For saving PNG images on your device, look into [**`UIImagePNGRepresentation`**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIImagePNGRepresentation) which is part of the [UIImage Class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

As for changing the app icon, this would only be possible if you are jailbroken and have the right package dependencies that allow the icons to refresh in SpringBoard on the fly.

Outside of being Jailbroken, changing the app icon would require an app update which would include the new icon.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't think it's possible for the actual icon for the app to change, because it's set on the phone when the app is installed.